# c# safest way check whether a type contains a type in its interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection

what is the safest way to compare two types at runtime ?

```
public interface IHandler<T> where T : Command {

}

public class CleanupHandler : IHandler<CleanupCommand> {
}

var Handlers = GetServices(typeof(IHandler<Cleanup>));


static IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
            var services= _services.Where(r => r.implementationType.GetInterfaces().Contains(serviceType)) /* issue here */
                                   .Select(r => r.implementation);

            return services;
 }
```

`_services` is an Enumerable of

```
public class Metadata {
    public Type serviceType { get; protected set; }
    public Type implementationType { get; protected set; }
    public object implementation { get; protected set; }
}
```

if we change the check from :

```
r.implementationType.GetInterfaces().Contains(serviceType)
```

to

```
r.implementationType.GetInterfaces().Count(x => x.Name == serviceType.Name) > 0
```

it works but thats not safe at all , the type is indeed the same but it doesnt work.

Edit :

```
namespace ConsoleApp {
    class Command {

    }

    interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : Command {

    }

    class Cleanup : Command {

    }

    class CleanupHandler: ICommandHandler<Cleanup> {

    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(r => r.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

can i have a hint?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Something that we can copy, paste, and run? Please include a function that takes the type inputs and returns `bool` - we can then fill in that method.

Comment: @Enigmativity i edited my question ! the list is returned as an empty list when its expected to return the type `CleanupHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `ICommandHandler<>` isn't really an interface per se. You can never assign anything to it, for example. It is a *type definition* or sometimes called an open generic type.

I think you are looking for any type that has a type definition of `ICommandHandler<>`. If that is the case, I think you want

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetExportedTypes()
    .Where
    (
        r => r.GetInterfaces().Any
        (
            i => i.IsGenericType 
              && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
        )
    );
```